# how to access state of a textview from within arrayAdapter's viewOnclick?

Tags: android, view, arraylist, adapter

I've an app that has a listView of client data. Each row in the listView will hold name, address, telNo etc. I get the data from a webcall and then populate an ArrayList with the data that is going to back the Adapter.

When the user click on a row in the list then in the onClick of the adapter i get the phone number and start an intent that starts the dialer activity. This all works well.

The client's telno always comes from the webcall, but in the view i have logic that determines whether it is displayed or not. Some companies do not want client numbers displayed while others do.

How can i determine if the TextView that holds the number is being displayed in the view at runtime? I set a tag that i pass to the onclick that has the row in the listView that has been clicked but how can i use something like

```
if(Textview.isShown)
```

inside the onClick? What i eventually want is, if the textview is shown that holds the number then the user can click to bring the dialer up else the dialer will not dial the number(even though it is present in the list, just not showing).

Thanks in advance Matt.
.

```
 private class MySimpleArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {




            private final Context context;
            private final ArrayList<?> list;



            public MySimpleArrayAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<?> list) {

                super(context, R.layout.getrotadetailsrow);
                Log.e(TAG, "inside adapter constructor");
                this.context = context;
                this.list = list;


            }

            @Override
            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

                View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.getrotadetailsrow, parent,
                        false);
                String record = list.get(position).toString();
                String[] recordArray = record.split(",");

                //recordArray[6] = ****the telephone number****

                rowView.setTag(record);

                TextView telNo =  (TextView) rowView
                        .findViewById(R.id.telNo);

    if(someCondition){

         telNo.setText("TelNo: " + recordArray[6]);

         }else{

            telNo.setVisibility(View.GONE);

          }

                return rowView;
            }

            @Override
            public int getCount() {
                return this.list.size();
            }

    }//end of adapter


    @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {


            String record = (String)view.getTag();

            String[] itemsInRecord = record.split(",");

            String telNo = itemsInRecord[6];




                String numberToDial = "tel:" + telNo;
                startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, Uri.parse(numberToDial)));


        }
```

.

[edit1]

```
public class GetRotaDetails extends NfcBaseActivity implements OnItemClickListener{



    ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> array;

    private static final String TAG = GetRotaDetails.class.getSimpleName();
    NfcScannerApplication nfcscannerapplication;
    String callID;
    ListView listView;
    Intent intent;
    MySimpleArrayAdapter arrayAdapter;
    SharedPreferences  appSharedPrefs;
    Handler handler;
    Runnable runnable;
    String rotaAutoLogout;
    int rotaAutoLogoutAsInt;
    String postcodeToPassToDirections;
    String postcodeWithoutSpaces;
    public static final String CUSTOM_QRCODE_ACTION = "com.carefreegroup.QRCODE_ACTION";
    String carerID;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        ///////////set titlebar to carer's name///////////////////////
        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        nfcscannerapplication = (NfcScannerApplication) getApplication();
        intent = this.getIntent();

        setContentView(R.layout.getrotadetailslayout);
        array = new  ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.getrotadetailslistview);






    }// end of onCreate











    private class AsyncGetRotaDetails extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        ProgressDialog progressDialog;
        String rotaDetails = null;



        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) { 

            try {
                Log.e(TAG, "inside doInBackground");

                rotaDetails = nfcscannerapplication.loginWebservice.getRotaDetail(params[0]);

            } catch (Exception e) {

                e.printStackTrace();

            }
            return rotaDetails;

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String xmlResult) {
            super.onPostExecute(xmlResult);
            if (progressDialog != null)
                progressDialog.dismiss();

                RetrieveExtraDetails red = new RetrieveExtraDetails();
                array = red.getExtraDetails(xmlResult);
                Log.e(TAG, "array from WS = " + array.size());

                if (arrayAdapter == null){
                    MySimpleArrayAdapter arrayAdapter = new MySimpleArrayAdapter(GetRotaDetails.this, array);
                    listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
                    listView.setOnItemClickListener(GetRotaDetails.this);
                 }//end if

        }// end of postExecute

    }//end of Async




    private class MySimpleArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {




        private final Context context;
        private final ArrayList<?> list;



        public MySimpleArrayAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<?> list) {

            super(context, R.layout.getrotadetailsrow);
            Log.e(TAG, "inside adapter constructor");
            this.context = context;
            this.list = list;


        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.getrotadetailsrow, parent,
                    false);
            String record = list.get(position).toString();
            String[] recordArray = record.split(",");
            rowView.setTag(record);



             TextView telNo = (TextView) rowView
                        .findViewById(R.id.telno);





            if(  someCondition ){  


                telNo.setVisibility(View.GONE);



            }else {
                telNo.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                telNo.setText("TelNo: " + recordArray[6]);
            }

                }

            }

            return rowView;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return this.list.size();
        }

}//end of adapter




    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {


        String record = (String)view.getTag();

        String[] itemsInRecord = record.split(",");

        String telNo = itemsInRecord[6];




            String numberToDial = "tel:" + telNo;
            startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, Uri.parse(numberToDial)));


    }





    }// end of class
```

Comment: You need to initialize textview on list item c

          `TextView tv = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.textView1)` then check the visibility

Comment: @Raghunandan Could you expand on what you mean. I've tried inializing the textview inside the ArrayAdapter's constuctor but i can't seen to access it from within onClick

Comment: you want to access textview on listitem click? why are you initializing in adapter constructor. i am confused as to what you want actually

Comment: yes, when the user clicks a row on the listview, the onClick should check to see whether the textview is showing in the listview and then show the dialer with the number in or not.

Comment: i'm initializing in adapter constructor because i though that is what you meant.

Comment: in your activity class in listview on item click listener override on item click and then initialize textview there and then do what is required

Comment: check my post i am not sure if i understand your requirement correctly. do try it and let me know

Comment: @Raghunandan Hi I've included the entire source(cut out alot that doesn't apply). Edit 1 include the class, how i get the data, setting up the adapter and listview etc. If you look at the Adapter's getView, i instantiate the textView telNo. I then test some condition and then set its visiblity there. What i would like is access the textview's visibility status inside the onclick. Thanks

Comment: try the code i posted in onItemClick in your onItemCLick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to initialize textview on list item click

```
 @Override
 public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)        
             {
             TextView tv = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.textView1);
              if (tv.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                   // Its visible
             } else {
            // Either gone or invisible
             }
             }
 });
```

On item click you have the view as a param to your `onItemClick`. So use the view object to initialize textview

```
    TextView tv = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.textView1);
```

Then do what is needed with the textview tv.

Comment: Thanks works fine now. I'm not sure how it works, maybe the textview is passed in with the view obj that is passed to the onClick. Thanks alot.

Comment: you get the view `View view` in `onItemClick` the view of the row clicked ( the entire view with textview and other views). so all you need to do is initialize the textview for the row and then check the visibility. create the correct answer. which part should i edit?